# Authentication not working with Supabase and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, supabase

I am not sure even this is possible but I am trying to use Supabase with Node.js. I get the code from a React front-end, this [link](https://dev.to/dabit3/10-minute-tutorial-full-stack-github-authentication-with-supabase-react-3c6b), which works okay.

Below is my code

**client.js**

```
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js')

const supabaseUrl = "MY_URL"
const public_anon_key = "MY_ANON_KEY"
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl,public_anon_key)

exports.supabase = supabase
```

**app.js**

```
const { supabase }  = require('./client')

async function signOut() {
        /* sign the user out */
        await supabase.auth.signOut();
}

async function signInWithGithub() {
        /* authenticate with GitHub */
        await supabase.auth.signIn({
                provider: 'github'
        });
}

async function printUser() {
        const user = supabase.auth.user()
        console.log(user.email)
}

signInWithGithub()
printUser()
signOut()
```

I am new to Node.js and I suspect something wrong with Promises is missing.
Is it possible to retrieve the `user` data from Supabase, if so, what is my code missing?

Thanks

Edit : title

Comment: I have the exact same problem when building a Vercel serverless API (which is Node). getUser() returns a 500 error and the user variable is null. Of course nothing interesting in the Supabase log. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: `const { user, session, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
  email: 'example@email.com',
  password: 'example-password',
})`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Supabase does but the problem seems to be Promise related

Try to change your app.js as follow

```
const { supabase }  = require('./client')

function signOut() {
        /* sign the user out */
        supabase.auth.signOut();
}

function signInWithGithub() {
        /* authenticate with GitHub */
        return  supabase.auth.signIn({
                provider: 'github'
        });
}
function printUser() {
        const user = supabase.auth.user()
        console.log(user.email)
}

signInWithGithub().then(() => {
   printUser()
   return signOut()

})
```

Comment: Thanks but still gives me the same error message, i.e. usr is null and cannot read properties of null.

Answer (score 0):

Since `@supabase/supabase-js` up to v2 (at time of writing) is meant for JAMstack developers, it does take some additional configuration to use it for the Node.js environment.

You will need to some additional configuration:

```
// ANON_KEY and ANON_URL are string constants from your project
createClient(ANON_URL, ANON_KEY, {
    auth: { persistSession: false, autoRefreshToken: false },
})
```

This will disable attempts by the client to store and refresh session, as there is no localStorage in server/scripting environments.